# map inside structure in c++

Tags: c++, dictionary

I defined a structure and a vector of the structure.I took input by a temporary structure of the type bind and pushed it back into the vector.

```
typedef struct {
        string bindername ;
        map<string ,long long int> m ;
        int index ;
    }bind ; 
    vector <bind> v ;
```

Inside main function , I declared an iterator it as :

```
map <string ,long long int>::iterator it ;
```

When I am trying to access vector's member by iterator it , I am having errors .
I tried to access it like this :

```
int l = v.size () ;
for (int K = 0 ; K < l ; K++)
        {
            for (it = v[K].m.begin () ;it != v[K].m.end () ; it++) // this line is generating errors
            {
                if ((it->second ()) < b) //this line is also generating errors // b is an int
                {
                    cout << it -> first () << endl ;
                    c++ ;
                }
            }
```

Errors generated :

```
b.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
b.cpp:84:22: error: ‘it.std::_Rb_tree_iterator<_Tp>::operator-> [with _Tp = std::pair<const std::basic_string<char>, long long int>, std::_Rb_tree_iterator<_Tp>::pointer = std::pair<const std::basic_string<char>, long long int>*]()->std::pair<const std::basic_string<char>, long long int>::second’ cannot be used as a function
b.cpp:86:27: error: no match for call to ‘(const std::basic_string<char>) ()’
```

How can I access V[K].m's second elements by iterator it to check whether it is less then b or not ?

Comment: `first` and `second` aren't functions.

Answer (score 3):

You do `it->second ()` which is a function call, but the `second` member is not a function, it's an integer. You do the same with the `first` element of the iterator two lines down.

Answer (score 2):

The two public members of `std::pair` are objects, not functions.

So `it->second()` should be `it->second`.

Answer (score 1):

```
if ((it->second ()) < b)
//              ^^
```

You have a set of parenthesis so the compiler thinks you're incorrectly calling a function.

Answer (score 1):

`it->second < b`

second is a data member, not a function.